# Raspberry Ketone Dietary Supplement? Fat-burning? Legit?

Tags: body-fat, supplement, drug-metabolism, ketone, fad-diet

So I found (not expired or opened) a bottle of dietary supplements in my cabinet called "Ketone Raspberry" and it claims to "promote body fat reduction", "support increased metabolism," and "PROMOTE WEIGHT LOSS" (that part is in much bigger font).

Now I don't believe in a magic pill that will make you fit again (I'm all for traditional methods and plan to stick to that), but I was wondering if there is some element of truth to this? Does it help increase the metabolism?

On the back it states:

> Raspberry Ketone helps to Block Fat -- by encouraging the body to use
>   fat instead of storing it, which can help you lose weight. In order to
>   get enough ketone to urn excess fat, you would need to eat 90 lbs of
>   raspberries! Forget that! Taking just 1 tablet of Raspberry Ketone
>   with meals is enough to get your body burning fat the way you want it
>   to!

Really? Really? This sounds like a fad diet to me. Has this worked for anyone out there?

Comment: Used it, and felt that it didn't do anything, other than give a rather pleasant raspberry aftertaste. As you say, only the tried-and-true, and healthy approaches work. I offer this as a comment, as it's more of an opinion than an answer.

Comment: Think about it: If it did what they claim, why would you need to ask? It would be a worldwide sensation that everyone knows about.